# HTML Website Search Form

Tags: html, search

I am trying to add an extra parameter to a website search form.

http://jsfiddle.net/n8SVV/

What I have added is the first group of html code (Campus), but this does not appear to interact with the search in any meaningful way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the server-side script isn't programmed to search against those new form fields, or you don't have access to the server side to program it yourself, you're out of luck.  Just sending data to a script doesn't mean it is going to do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in the form and the search isn't affected, one of two things is going on:

- The script that handles submissions is expecting the campus to be specified in a different variable (maybe it expects "school_campus" or "campus_choice," etc)
- The script doesn't support a campus parameter.

The root cause behind both cases is that you can't just throw data at a script and expect it to work. What does the documentation for the campus search API say, if such a thing exists?

I don't even see a campus selection on the destination page, so I'm betting that your issue is the second one.